# bucklespring cannot load libfluidsynth.so.1

Tags: 20.04

I installed `bucklespring` via `sudo apt install bucklespring`.

Installing `bucklespring` does not seem sufficient to enable keyboard sounds.

Invoking `buckle` seems to be necessary and it is in `/usr/games`.

Once `buckle` is invoked keyboard sounds are enabled but the Terminal command line prompt does not return and the Terminal displays...

> Error loading libfluidsynth.so.1: libfluidsynth.so.1: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory

What is the flawless way to install and enable `bucklespring` ?

**Addendum...**

- `sudo apt install fluidsynth` does not solve the problem of the error message.
- I am now preferring to put `/usr/games/buckle -f &` in `~/.bashrc`.  The `&` will background it. Thanks @guiverc.  The `-f` option means play a default sound if a sound file is missing which is what happens for some parts of a numeric keypad.

Comment: It's a program that of course needs to be executed; it's not a *daemon* that runs in the background (*though you can run it in the background*).  How you run it depends on how you want to run it, you could have it autostart though I'd not like that (*personally I vary the volume depending on what I'm doing so manual execution makes more sense to me*)

Comment: Looks like libfluidsynth.so is in libfluidsynth-dev...

Comment: @andrew.46 Thanks but installing libfluidsynth-dev did not make a difference.

Comment: @H2ONaCl You may need a symlink if your application is specifically looking for `libfluidsynth.so.1`. What does the command `sudo find /usr -iname libfluidsynth.so*` show?

Comment: @andrew.46 `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so.2.3.1` 
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so` 
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfluidsynth.so.2`